# How can I apply McNemar’s test in matched case control study on SPSS?

Tags: inference, biostatistics, epidemiology, mcnemar-test

When conducting a case-control study with 120 cases 1:1 to 120 controls and examining whether they had a binary exposure prior to developing the disease. I am using conditional logistic regression for the main analysis. My question is, when I do bivariate initial analysis to determine which variable associations are significant to Be considered in the multivariate regression, do I use McNemar’s test? How do I use McNemar’s test in SPSS as it is not a pre/post variable study?